# Filtering a column inside a formula

Tags: excel, csv, sqlconnection

I am getting data from table in a database and I have created a connection in excel. I was to allow the user to enter a ID in field C3 and the table will filter all the ID's by this number.  I know I can filter the data manually via ID however I have no idea how to filter by a number in a cell - I have tried to create a custom filter but it won't allow me to reference a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hm, you could of course add a column with a formula like this

```
=A1=$C$3
```

and then apply your filter to this colum and filter, when result = true